# Stack segment in the MikeOS bootloader

Tags: assembly, bootloader

I don't understand this piece of code:

```
mov ax, 07C0h   ; Set up 4K of stack space above buffer
add ax, 544     ; 8k buffer = 512 paragraphs + 32 paragraphs (loader)
cli             ; Disable interrupts while changing stack
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 4096
sti             ; Restore interrupts
```

- mov ax, 07C0h - here BIOS loads our
  code. But what is '4K'? Kilobytes? I
  didn't get it :)
- add ax, 544 - Why again '8K'? And why we add 544? Why not 512?
- mov sp, 4096 - Here we set stack pointer.

What for do we do all these manipulations, before we set stack pointer?

Comment: Have you got the source to the rest of the boot loader?

Comment: Yes. It is available here http://mikeos.berlios.de/#downloads or I shared it here http://snipt.org/Tmon

Comment: Slight tangent: I could be wrong on this, and I don't have the Intel manual handy to check, but I think the `CLI` and `STI` instructions are unnecessary here. IIRC, it's guaranteed that if a move to `SS` is immediately followed by a move to `SP`, then no interrupts shall occur between the two move instructions.

Comment: The `MOV/ADD` sequence is unnecessary too - it could just be one `MOV` instruction

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the comment on the last line sums it up:

```
buffer:             ; Disk buffer begins (8k after this, stack starts)
```

The memory layout looks like this:

```
+-------------------+ <-- 07C0:0000, where the BIOS loads the boot sector
| 512 bytes of code |
+-------------------+
| 8KB set aside for |
|   a disk buffer   |
+-------------------+ <-- SS:0000
|   4KB of stack    |
+-------------------+ <-- SS:1000 = SS:SP
```

The comment about paragraphs is slightly obtuse; I find it easier to think in bytes, where 16 bytes makes one paragraph.

The reason for these magic numbers:

- Start at segment 07C0, where the BIOS loads the code
- Skip past 512 bytes, to account for the code itself (512 bytes = 32 paragraphs)
- Skip past 8KB, to set aside space for the disk buffer (8,192 bytes = 512 paragraphs)
- Put SS at the start of a 4KB block. **512+8192 = 8,704 bytes = 544 paragraphs**
- Put SP at the end of that block. Put it at the end because the stack needs to grow upwards in memory.

Note that the number 4096 = 4KB appears as normal in the code, because the SP register needs a value in bytes. All the other values are in paragraphs because they relate to SS, which is a segment register.

Comment: Could I ask, how does a programmer know they have to do all this? Where is the manual for this, I don't even know what manual I should look at? (I mean where is the manual that says 07C0h is where BIOS loads the code)

Comment: @gideon This kind of detail dates back to the original IBM PC, so it would have been documented by IBM, and reproduced by manufacturers of PC clones. Later in the 80s and 90s we had books like [PC Intern](http://www.amazon.com/PC-Intern-Encyclopedia-Programming-Developers/dp/1557553041/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1381938577&sr=8-1&keywords=pc+intern). And now this kind of obscure knowledge circulates on sites such as http://wiki.osdev.org, and of course Stack Overflow.